# js REGEX | Get the last two sets of Numbers in a string, How?

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers

I have Strings in this format:

> 6b255c1c689e2e7ee88e6d5d8ab10e9b_307_17234.jpg
>
> 8b342878cb8d848608d422a2c02b5e32_7_240723.jpg
>
> 07e8e2376d12e2d20a1e4c2159569c43_243_141599.jpg

How do you get the last 2 sets of Numbers?

For example,
in

> 07e8e2376d12e2d20a1e4c2159569c43_243_141599.jpg

I want to get:

> 07e8e2376d12e2d20a1e4c2159569c43_**243_141599**.jpg *Only the **Numbers** in bold with the **underscore** in between them*

Is it possible??.....

**I tried:** `var getDigts = str.split('_'), //this way is ok but I have to split again  the getDigts[2] as in str2.split(".") to get rid of the DOT.`

Is there a workaround  or something quicker than double `split` with plain `REGEX`?
Thx

**EDIT**

I tried to use `str.match(/(\d+_\d+).jpg/)[1]` as suggested by @Michael Best ... Just experienced a big **ERROR:** The reason is because am looping through each string to get the numbers... NOW, Should there be something like:

> 6b255c1c689e2e7ee88e6d5d8ab10e9b_307_17234.jpg
>   8b342878cb8d848608d422a2c02b5e32_7_240723.jpg
>   649ff5658ad274d8cee67b1f6d34600c_90_182456.png
>   07e8e2376d12e2d20a1e4c2159569c43_243_141599.jpg

***Notice the:*** `.png` line. is there a REGEX to match both `.jpg` and/or `.png` at the same time?

I tried to remove the `jpg` from the `.jpg` something like: `str.match(/(\d+_\d+)./)[1]` but this fails when it comes to strings like: `07e8e2376d12e2d20a1e4c2159569c43_243_141599.jpg`

it returns

> 07e8e2376d12e2d20a1e4c **2159569c43_243** _141599.jpg

instead of

> 07e8e2376d12e2d20a1e4c2159569c43_**243_141599**.jpg

Any Help is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick-and-dirty regex:

```
var nums = str.match(/(\d+_\d+)\.\w+$/)[1];
```

Comment: Man you save me Hours of Googling... WorkedGreatly... Thanks

Comment: The dot matches any character, so I changed it match a literal dot.

Comment: Thax a mili... is it case insensitive?... or do i have to add the  `i` at the end?

Comment: The \w is case insensitive.

Comment: I've added a `$` to the end to ensure it matches the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
str.match(/(\d+_\d+).JPG|PNG/i)[1]
```

When you say: `.JPG|.PNG` and you add the `i` athe end, you are telling the script to look for those extensions in a case insensitive way.

So it will match both `.jpg` and `.png`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You should try this regexp.

```
str.match(/(\d+_\d+)\.(?:jpg|png)/i)[1]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/FdYn5N4hSodp5BoM)

The `.` have to be escaped as well. `.` is a wildcard for nearly all characters. If not escaped then

```
1233242_34243_3224_png_3424_34342.jpg
```

Whould give a wrong match `34243_3224`.

Because of using case insensitivity with `i`-flag **PNG** and **png** (JPG, jpg) would be matched as extensions.